# Filter after Groupby and Sum in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

below is the table generated after groupby and Sum of paramount. 
I would like to filter out this table by sum , like >0, <0 etc

```
            paramount
            sum
CP  AD  IID

aa  bb  ccc 0

aa  bb  ddd 0

aa  bb  eee 10
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "etc"?

Comment: @coldspeed and salah , could u check the table now , the last column is the calculated table after grouped by CP,AD,IID . I would like to filter using the Paramount - Sum column

Comment: you can add what you have already tried - input, query/code, output and your desired output

Comment: s=t.groupby(['CP  ','AD','IID']).aggregate({'paramount':['sum']}) ....
ss= s[s['sum'] >0]

Comment: @prdp13 - better ia avoid MultiIndex in columns, check my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as passing the condition that you wish to evaluate, if I understand the question correctly.

```
df = df[df["paramount"]["sum"] > 0]
```